# Auf dem Stuhl vs auf den Stuhl

Tags: dative, accusative

Recently I have come across this sentence in my german textbook: 
"Stellen Sie sich hinter den Stuhl. Der Rücken ist gerade. Wenn Sie hinter dem Stuhl stehen, dann legen Sie die Hände auf den Stuhl.

Gehen Sie jetzt in die knie - der Rücken bleibt gerade und die Hände liegen auf dem Stuhl."

My questions are: why den is used in the first sentence after hinter while dem is used after the same word in the following sentence? I also wonder why auf den Stuhl is used at the end of first paragraph while auf dem Stuhl is used in the second paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two sentences is that the first one

> Stellen Sie sich hinter den Stuhl.

denotes a directed movement. The target position is denoted with the accusative case ("den Stuhl").

In contrast, the second sentence contains a description of a location:

> Wenn Sie hinter dem Stuhl stehen, ...

This uses the dative case.